# DataTemplate in listview

Tags: wpf, listview, datatemplate

I use a listview to display data like a data matrix (columns and rows). My problem is : my items are typed : MatrixCellVM.
I tried everything I found on the net to apply a DataTemplate on this items but nothing worked.

Here is the latest technique I'm using

```
foreach (var col in dataMatrix.Columns)
{
    //create the data template
    DataTemplate cellLayout = new DataTemplate();
    cellLayout.DataType = typeof(MatrixCellVM);

    //set up the stack panel
    FrameworkElementFactory spFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Grid));
    spFactory.Name = "myComboFactory";

    //set up value textblock
    FrameworkElementFactory cellValue = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
    cellValue.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding("Value"));
    cellValue.SetValue(TextBlock.ToolTipProperty, "Value");
    spFactory.AppendChild(cellValue);

    //set the visual tree of the data template
    cellLayout.VisualTree = spFactory;

    gridView.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn{
        Header = col.Name,
        DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding(string.Format("[{0}]", count)),
        CellTemplate = cellLayout
    });
    count++;
}
```

One more thing, when I override ToString() in MatrixCellVM, the value is displayed (but with this technique I add a context menu or give any color to my value).

Comment: I've removed your tag from the title of the question - the tag you've added is enough :-)  Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: The MatrixCellVM class has a Value property. I just want to display it in a textblock. How could I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem but have another one.

So what I did is pretty simple. DisplayMemberBinding and CellTemplate can't be put together.

So I deleted the whole c# code creating the datatemplate.

The only thing that remains is :

```
gridView.Columns.Add(
                new GridViewColumn
                    {
                        Header = col.Name,
                        CellTemplate = (DataTemplate)listView.Resources["MatrixCellVMTemplate"]
                    });
```

Thus, I added  in my xaml code defining the datatemplate.

My new problem is that my rows are arrays of MatrixCellVM (as it is a matrix, I don't have properties and I don't know by advance how many columns I will have).

That was the point of the DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding(string.Format("[{0}]",count)) code in my top post.

How could I reproduce this behavior in my datatemplate (what is the binding in my textblock).

If anything is not clear, let me know.

Thanks